# What sounds better My lovely Kellisa or the lovely kellisa

Tags: poetry, shakespeare

Am wrting a poem for a beautiful girl in my advanced English class and the last thing I want is for her to think I don't care about her (its freshman advanced English)

Comment: Opinion-based, but 'my' is less impersonal.

Comment: Her name is unusual and she may not like having it splashed around. You might want to use another name....just saying....

Comment: Generally it's considered more polite to capitalize a person's name.

Comment: When you have finished writing your poem I suggest you run a spelling check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is tough.  In a poem you can get away with anything if you are clever enough. Here is an example of of  a (presumably beautiful) girl being compared to (good heavens) a time interval:

*Shall I compare thee to a summer's day? Thou art more lovely and more 
   temperate. Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May, And summer's lease 
   hath all too short a date.*

So you have an opportunity to stretch for art.  Just go with your gut, and if you fall then fall from a great height.

Comment: @Edwin & Co,  you have completely failed to see what the questioner was really after.